# Run an external .class file through Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am actually developing a compiler as part of a university assignment. My code already generates `.class` files that can be run from cmd. But I have been trying to find a way to run the `.class` file generated through netbeans itself. I have tried adding the `.class` file as a folder under the `"libraries"` folder but cannot use it in my code.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Right now I am using the following code to run the `.class` file:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String []{"java", "-cp", dir.toString(), className});
        OutputStream pIn = process.getOutputStream();
      //  InputStream pOut = process.getInputStream();
        try(InputStream in = process.getInputStream()){
            return new Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        }
```

This is inside a function which returns a string. The `.class` file requests for user input and hence, when i run the project, it keeps running but nothing appears on the console.

Comment: What error are you getting while running from netbeans ?

Comment: Hello. I have just edited the post for clarification. I am new to stackoverflow, so if you need more information on the code, let me know. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: What values are you using in this array of string.."java", "-cp", dir.toString(), className

Comment: The directory of my `.class` file. The command is "java -cp C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaTest\compilerTest and className is CodeTesting.class

Comment: When the `.class` file is executed from cmd, the program prints a "Hello World" message and asks the user to input a number.